# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError during cassandra trigger creation

Tags: cassandra, kafka-producer-api

Hello I am writing small cassandra trigger that sends information to kafka after insert to a certain table. Here's my trigger code:

```
public class InsertDataTrigger implements ITrigger {

    public Collection<Mutation> augment(Partition update) {

        //checking if trigger works and some debug info;
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println("Hello " + dateFormat.format(new Date()));
        System.out.println("This Insert Data Trigger");
        System.out.println("default charset " + Charset.defaultCharset());      //IMPORTANT check if it's important

        //here we're gonna build the message to kafka based on inserted data
        try {
            UnfilteredRowIterator it = update.unfilteredIterator();
            CFMetaData cfMetaData = update.metadata();

            System.out.println("PartitionKey " + new String(update.partitionKey().getKey().array()));
            System.out.println("update.metadata().clusteringColumns().toString() " + update.metadata().clusteringColumns().toString());

            while (it.hasNext()) {
                JSONObject message = new JSONObject();

                Unfiltered un = it.next();
                Clustering clt = (Clustering) un.clustering();

                message.put("partitionkey", new String(update.partitionKey().getKey().array()));

                System.out.println("clt.toString(cfMetaData) " + clt.toString(cfMetaData));
                System.out.println("clt.getRawValues() " + new String(clt.getRawValues()[0].array()));
                System.out.println("partition.columns().toString() " + update.columns().toString());

                message.put("datetime", new String(clt.getRawValues()[0].array()));

                Iterator<Cell> cells = update.getRow(clt).cells().iterator();

                while (cells.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cells.next();
                    System.out.println("cell.column().name.toString() " + cell.column().name.toString());
                    System.out.println("cell.toString()" + cell.toString());
                    Double x = cell.value().getDouble();
                    System.out.println("cell.value().getDouble() " + x);
                    //if(cell.column().name.toString() == "value")
                    System.out.println(x);
                    message.put(cell.column().name.toString(), x);
                    //else
                    //   message.put(cell.column().name.toString(),cell.value().toString());
                }
                System.out.println("un.toString()" + un.toString(cfMetaData));

                if (!message.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println(message.toString());

                    //Sending data to kafka
                    Properties props = new Properties();
                    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
                    props.put("acks", "all");
                    props.put("retries", 0);
                    props.put("batch.size", 16384);
                    props.put("linger.ms", 1);
                    props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
                    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
                    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

                    Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
                    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("test", message.toString()));//move topic name to some properties
                    producer.close();
                }


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return Collections.emptyList();
    } }
```

And here is my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.1</version>
               <configuration>
                   <source>1.8</source>
                   <target>1.8</target>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>

   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>io.github.carldata</groupId>
   <artifactId>InsertDataTrigger</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>

   <dependencies>
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cassandra/cassandra-all -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
           <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
           <version>3.11.0</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
           <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
           <version>0.11.0.0</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>

</project>
```

The project builds fine and creates a jar file , but when I try to create trigger in cassandra it fails with mentioned exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the kafka-clients jar isn't in the Cassandra lib directory. Unless your project is including that dependency in it (ie build a fat/uber jar).

You *may* have problems with conflicts of dependancies in the kafka-clients jar and the Cassandra dependancies. In particular `org.xerial.snappy snappy-java` have different versions. It may work out but its something to look out for.If its a problem you can build own your Kafka clients jar with its dependancies shaded so they don't conflict.

Comment: Thank you very much I have created uber jar and it solved the problem.